# NoClassDefFoundError while connecting remote host using JSCH API

Tags: java, jsch

I'm working on a project where I need to connect to remote AIX host to pull .zip file using JSCH API.

The code working fine in development and AT environment.

But in UAT environment its not working as expected, even though both AT and UAT are point to same remote host.

I'm getting below error NoClassDefFoundError for class
     org/bouncycastle/crypto/modes/SICBlockCipher.

Please find the snap of code and the exception.

We currently in UAT phase. Your help will be appriciated

```
     JSch jsch= null;  
     Session session= null; 
     Channel channel= null; 
     InputStream in= null; 
     ChannelSftp channelSftp = null; 

     jsch=new JSch(); 
     session=jsch.getSession(remoteUserId, remoteHostName, 22); 
     session.setPassword(remotePassword); 
     session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no"); 

     channel = session.openChannel("sftp"); 
     channel.connect(); 
     channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel; 
     Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> fileList= channelSftp.ls(remoteImageDir);



     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/crypto/modes/SICBlockCipher 
     at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineSetMode(Source) 
     at javax.crypto.Cipher$a_.a(Unknown Source) 
     at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source) 
     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source) 
     at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source) 
     at com.jcraft.jsch.jce.AES256CTR.init(AES256CTR.java:57) 
     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkCipher(Session.java:2072) 
     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkCiphers(Session.java:2049) 
     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.send_kexinit(Session.java:592) 
     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:286) 
     at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:162)
```

Comment: Is all of bouncy castle, and the correct version, in the class path or packaged with the jar on the UAT?